# Pattern Matching with Multiple Regex in Scala

Tags: scala

I am attempting to make a lexer in Scala.
I am attempting to do something like this

```
def lex(s: String): Expr = s match {
  case num(a)    => Number(a.toDouble)
  case mul(a, b) => Mul(Number(a.toDouble), Number(b.toDouble))
  case div(a, b) => Div(Number(a.toDouble), Number(b.toDouble))
  case add(a, b) => Add(Number(a.toDouble), Number(b.toDouble))
  case sub(a, b) => Sub(Number(a.toDouble), Number(b.toDouble))
  case   _       => Number(0)
}
```

where num, mul, div, add, sub are defined as so:

```
val num: Regex = "[0-9]+".r
val add: Regex = "[0-9]+\\s*\\+\\s*[0-9]+".r
val sub: Regex = "[0-9]+\\s*\\-\\s*[0-9]+".r
val div: Regex = "[0-9]+\\s*\\/\\s*[0-9]+".r
val mul: Regex = "[0-9]+\\s*\\*\\s*[0-9]+".r
```

When attempting to lex any expression (`lex("1 + 2")`) the result is always `Number(0.0)` instead of the expected `Add(Number(1), Number(2))`
Im not sure where it's going wrong...

Comment: You can use [the `raw` interpolator](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html#the-raw-interpolator) to avoid having to use double back-slashes. For example: `raw"[0-9]+\s*\+\s*[0-9]+".r`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify which groups you want to extract.

```
val num = "([0-9]+)".r
val add = "([0-9]+)\\s*\\+\\s*([0-9]+)".r
val sub = "([0-9]+)\\s*\\-\\s*([0-9]+)".r
val div = "([0-9]+)\\s*\\/\\s*([0-9]+)".r
val mul = "([0-9]+)\\s*\\*\\s*([0-9]+)".r
```

You need one pair of parentheses per variable you extract.